# Conversion of float in if statement

Tags: c++, c

In following code:

```
float x = 0.23;
int z;

z = x;

if (x)
    printf("float %f will not be converted to 0!\n", x);

if (z)
    printf("this will not print!\n");
```

I thought that floating point number will be converted to integer and then checked if it is zero when used in `if` statement. Can someone please explain to me, why that is not the case?

edit:

(just to clarify what has been confusing me)
Since logical operators like `<` return `int`, I thought that `if` statement receives
integer value so conversion needs to be done. As pointed out by answers, it doesn't. Thank you everyone!

Comment: anything other than zero is true and zero is false!

Comment: What happens when you run this? What do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. type converting happens when operating with other types, and the integer will be converted to float when operating between them, for example: x + z // z will be converted to "float" before add with "x"
2. if used as an logical condition in "if()", it is only judged that "null/zero or not". 0.23 is not zero/null, so the result is TRUE.

Comment: Type converting also happens whenever small integer types are used in an expression. This is known as integer promotion. If you for example have `char a, b;` then take `sizeof(a+b)`, it is the same as `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 5):

> I thought that floating point number will be converted to integer and then checked if it is zero when used in if statement.

No, it will just be compared with zero. The rule for converting arithmetic types to boolean is given in C++11 4.12:

> A zero value [...] is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler will only check if the argument in `if` is `zero`. if not, the condition is `true`. No conversion is done at all.

Comment: Technically, the condition IS converted to a bool - but yes, it's compared against zero, not converted to anything else first.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Only in C++. This question is tagged with C and C++ both, for reasons unknown.

Comment: Well, C may not express that it "converts to bool", but it does a compare to zero, which gives a "true or false" result. Which to me is a bool conversion, even if the spec doesn't say so.

Answer (score 1):

Your first test is testing `x`, the `float`, so no "conversion" happens there.

Basically, the `if` will check if the expression is 0 or non-zero, and clearly 0.23 is  non-zero so that code should execute.

You can think of

```
if(x)
```

as being the same as

```
if(x != 0)
```

Comment: Basically, the `if` requires a `bool`; it is the conversion to bool which is (for any type `T`) `v != static_cast<T>( 0 )`.  (In general, it is probably better to avoid such implicit conversions.  They are confusing, and make the code harder to read.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a float in a boolean context, it will directly be checked if it is zero or not, without converting it to int first. So `0.23f` is `true`, while `(int)0.23f` is `false`.