# Don't understand what's going on in the "if" condition?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

A bit strange question. But unfortunately. I can't understand the logic that is written in the condition in the Unreal C++ code.

I have conditions in a member function:

```
void MoveForward(float amount)
{
  if (amount)
{
 // do that
}
}
```

What does **"amount"** parameter mean in a condition? What is the verification for? If it is **installed**? Or will it be **true**?
Sorry for the twisted question, unfortunately new to all this at the moment...

Comment: That's weird with a float, but that if statement is the same as if (amount != 0).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15000495/4944425

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In C and C++ `if` tests for a nonzero value. Anything that's nonzero is considered true. When it comes to floating point values, what exactly is a zero is something books can and have been written about, so don't do it if you want reliable code. It's safe to assume that it tests for `amount != 0.0f`.

But as far as the compiler is concerned, a float can be implcitly converted to an integer and that can be tested for nonzeroness.

Comment: i dont know C, but in C++ the condition is converted to `bool`, no integer involved afaik

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Well, to be fair, `bool` *is* an integral type (and `std::numeric_limits<bool>::is_integer` is also `true`), but yes, *"converted to an integer"* is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

It will considered as `true` if `amount` is not zero and `false` if `amount` is zero.

Quote from [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.4 Selection statements

> 4 The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch statement is the
> value of the declared variable contextually converted to bool (Clause 4).

Quote from N3337 4.12  Boolean conversions

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
> prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
> any other value is converted to true.

Comment: (So a NaN value is also considered true. This is at least consistent with `NAN != 0.0` being true.)